# How to add custom paragraph styles for Google Drive text documents

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

Currently, in Google Drive when editing a text document, there are 6 styles available:

- *Normal text*
- *Title*
- *Subtitle*
- *Heading 1*
- *Heading 2*
- *Heading 3*

These are not nearly enough for my style of writing. As a simple example, block quote is missing.

Is there any way to create more styles, with custom names?

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [Paragraph Styles+ Add-on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/paragraph-styles%20/pbfegackndhdneogcnlhhihgkphkggdh) for Google Docs. It allows you to create up to 6 new custom styles per document.

Comment: The app's not verified. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: That link is dead and the add-on appears to be gone, or renamed.

Answer (score -2):

This should help, I am not sure however how many fonts can be added but this is a good start.

https://support.google.com/drive/answer/189190?hl=en

Comment: I'm afraid just chainging fonts doesn't really cut it, since the typography of a paragraph in a specific font cannot be altered throughout the document.